# Handling routing with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I've just learned a bit of [CodeIgniter Framework](http://codeigniter.com) and I saw something which I wondered a long time ago.

CodeIgniter handles Routing just as this:

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php/classname/function/parameter
```

Now I want to get this to work:

```
http://mydomain.com/classname/function/parameter
```

Is it somehow possible to get the webserver to not check for the directories but to forward those parameters to mydomain.com/index.php? Is this somehow realizable by .htaccess or something?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the help regarding this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

or Place

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

in your .htaccess

Comment: Ah, I found it: You must add the line `Options +FollowSymLinks`, then this works great! Thank you!

Comment: I have added my answer please try this

Comment: We just edited the same :) the old post did work, you just had to add the Options Line